# ajax works in localhost but doesn't on hosting server

Tags: jquery, ajax

Everything is fine when my code runs in my localhost but uploaded to my hosting server it doesn't work. When I click the button nothing has change. Should I write an extra code to work on server? I added the code below. I hope someone help, thank you so much.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#giris").submit(function(event) 
    {
        var kullanici_adi=$("#kullanici_ad").val();
        var sifre=$("#sifre").val();

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "girisislemi.php",
            data: {kullanici_adi : kullanici_adi,sifre:sifre},
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) 
            { 
                if(data.tip==='yonetici'){window.location.href="yonetici.php";}
                if(data.tip==='kullanici'){window.location.href="kullanici.php";}
                if(data.tip==='hata')
                {
                    $('input[type=text]').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
                    $('input[type=password]').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
                    if (!$('.login-error').length)
                    {
                        $('#giris').after('<font><p class="login-error">Hatalı Bilgi</p></font>');
                    }
                    $('font').css("color","red");
                }
            }

        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

$("#cikis").click(function(event)
    {
        $.get( "cikisYap.php",function() {
        alert("Başarıyla çıkış yapıldı");
        window.location.href="index.php"
    });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You got to change `url`, I think.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what isn't working

Comment: @Patel they are on same path ,what should i do ?

Comment: Use your browser debug tools to see where is there's an error

Comment: @Amit can you suggest me please ?

Comment: did you check that you have uploaded all the files you need to run the project? Not only the php ones but for example jquery or other resources like that?

Comment: well , i added the same page jquery library link and the other pages

Comment: Test the server PHP files using a tool like fiddler2 to post to it and check the response.

Comment: as @RubyRacer said you should check the developer tools console to see if there are any errors/warnings. See http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/general-finding-the-development-tools.html

Comment: thank  you, @Thomas I have no error when i looked at console, but jquery.min,js status is 304 not modified . how can i fix this ?